# How to include QGLVIEWER in CMAKE for Qt5

Tags: c++11, cmake, qt5

I am setting CMAKE to include QGLViewer for a Qt5 project. However as soon as I try to compile the project CMAKE stops with the following error:

**CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
QGLVIEWER_LIBRARY
linked by target "sfm" in directory /home/emanuele/sfm**

QGLViewer is present on the following path: `usr/include/QGLViewer` as it is possible to see from this print screen:

[image: Print Screen of the File Path]
[image: This is the file path]

And here is how I set the path on CMAKE:

[image: CMAKE File Path]
[image: This is the file path in CMAKE]

Additionally I found [this source](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/kr_utils/blob/master/kr_cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindQGLViewer.cmake) that was helpful for understanding how to declare the lib. Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369464/qglviewer-simpleviewer-example-built-with-cmake-not-running) was useful to point me in the correct route, but still not working.

Below the most important CMAKE part that is causing the issue:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(sfm)

########### options ###############
SET(USE_QT TRUE CACHE BOOL)
########### END options ###########

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu99 -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -g")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

########### OpenMP ################
find_package(OpenMP)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
########### END OpenMP ############

########### OpenCV ################
set (OpenCV_DIR /home/emanuele/opencv/build)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
list(APPEND LINK_LIBRARIES ${OpenCV_LIBS})
########### END OpenCV ############

########### Qt 5 ##################
IF (USE_QT)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS("-DUSE_QT")
  find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
  find_package(Qt5Xml REQUIRED)
  find_package(Qt5OpenGL REQUIRED)

  include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
      ${Qt5Xml_INCLUDE_DIRS}
      ${Qt5OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )
  list(APPEND LINK_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Xml Qt5::OpenGL)
  set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
  set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

  include_directories(src/ui/mainwindow src/ui/widgets)

  find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
  find_library(QGLVIEWER_LIBRARY
      NAMES qglviewer-qt5 qglviewer QGLViewer QGLViewer2)
  list(APPEND LINK_LIBRARIES ${QGLVIEWER_LIBRARY}  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF (USE_QT)
########### END Qt 5 ##############

########### sources ###############
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(sfm ${SOURCE_FILES})
########### END sources ###########

########### headers ###############
include_directories(src)
########### END headers ###########

########### link libraries ########
target_link_libraries(sfm ${LINK_LIBRARIES})
########### END link libraries ####
```

I expect CMAKE to compile but the actual result I have is shown in the print screen below keeping me from moving ahead:

[image: Print Screen of the Error]
[image: This is the file path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the path of qglviewer library in CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable

or you may integrate it as a new target , using qglviewer tar gz archive as input :

```
set(QGLVIEWER_FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libQGLViewer-2.7.1/QGLViewer/qglviewer.h)

get_target_property (QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE Qt5::qmake IMPORTED_LOCATION)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${QGLVIEWER_FILES}
  COMMAND  tar xzf "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libQGLViewer-2.7.1.tar.gz" --strip 1
  COMMAND ${QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE} -o QMakefile 
  COMMAND make -f QMakefile 
#  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${LIBFOO_TAR_HEADERS}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libQGLViewer-2.7.1"
  DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libQGLViewer-2.7.1.tar.gz"
  COMMENT "Unpacking libQGLViewer-2.7.1.tar.gz"
  VERBATIM
)

add_custom_target(qglviewer_untar DEPENDS ${QGLVIEWER_FILES})

add_library(qglviewer SHARED IMPORTED)
add_dependencies(qglviewer qglviewer_untar)

# link qglviewer
set_target_properties(qglviewer PROPERTIES
                      IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libQGLViewer-2.7.1/QGLViewer/libQGLViewer-qt5.so"
                      INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libQGLViewer-2.7.1")
```